# How to forward port when using 3 routers?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking, port-forwarding, bridge

I've been struggling with my home network since I moved in but finally got to some results. Here's current set-up:

INTERNET ->
THOMSON 585V.7 (modem/Wi-Fi router) ->
wireless bridge ->
LINKSYS WRT54GL (Tomato firmware) ->
cable ->
D-LINK DIR655 (Wi-Fi router) ->
wireless ->
PC and laptop.

Here's a simple drawing so you get the idea: 
[image: Situation]

Now - how to forward ports for my PC through all that hardware on the way?
I tried and failed to do it separately on each machine. Not sure why...

Comment: Wait, how did you do a wireless repeater? I thought AP mode only worked over wired

Comment: @TheLQ He used a bridge device which is connected to a wireless router. The wireless router gets the bridge's signal as "WAN"...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's only one DHCP server active in your network since the devices all have an IP address in the same range 192.168.1.X. I'm assuming this is the Thomson router. Is this is true, you should just have to forward the port in that router instead of referring to the next hub on the way.

So in your Thomson router, just forward the port to the IP of your computer instead of the IP of the next hub.

Comment: Thanks for hint. I've tried that beforehand and it didn't work. Tried again now - still nothing. Actually - even after disabling firewalls on all devices all my ports seem to be closed and stealth according to  GRC ShieldsUp...